# How to use dependent types inside type classes in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, typeclass, dependent-type

I would like to define a pair of types  (`A` and `B` in `trait Dep[C]` ) for several different `C` -s. For example, `A=String` and `B=View` for `C`=`View1` (as defined in the implicit object `DepInstanceView1`). Then I would like to use these type level dependencies in type class definitions.

How can I define a type class instance (here `ServerSideFun[View1]`) that has functions with dependent input and return types  (here defined in `DepInstanceView1`)?

In other words, I would like to have a type level function that goes from `C -> (A,B)` (here one such type level mapping is defined in `DepInstanceView1`) and use this type level function inside a type class declaration (here `trait ServerSideFun[C]`) and its instances (here `View1Conv`).

Could someone please suggest a way how to do this ?

Or a way how to modify the code below to encode such type level, type dependent constraint on `f` (as it is implied in `trait ServerSideFun[C]`) in a type class ?

My attempt to do so ended up in a compiler error:

```
source_file.scala:47: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(42)
 required: B
    def f[A, B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[View1,A,B]):B = 42
                                                           ^
one error found
```

**The code example:**

The code below can be executed online here : http://rextester.com/GYWW78561

```
object Rextester extends App {
    println("Hello, World!3")
 }

trait Dep[C]{
  type A
  type B
}

trait View1
trait View2


object Dep{

  type Aux[C0, A0, B0]=  Dep[C0] {type A=A0; type B= B0}

  implicit object DepInstanceView1  extends  Dep[View1] {
    type A=String
    type B=Int
  } 
}

trait ServerSideFun[C]
{
   def f[A,B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[C,A,B]):B
}

object ServerSideFun {
  implicit object View1Conv extends ServerSideFun[View1]{
    def f[A, B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[View1,A,B]):B = 42
  }
}
```

EDIT :

I updated the code to clarify the intention : http://rextester.com/YVBV30174

which is:

1) to define several `View`-s :

- `trait View1`
- `trait View2`

2) for each of the `View`-s define a separate type level mapping `View -> (A,B)`, for example:

- `View1-> (String,Int)` in `DepInstanceView1`
- `View2-> (String,String)` in `DepInstanceView2`

3) make it possible to have several different implementations of the type class `ServerSideFun`, for example :

- one in `object ServerSideFun`
- another one in `object ServerSideFunAlternativeImplementation`.

**In essence** :

- **all** instances of the type class `ServerSideFun[C]` should adhere to the type level mappings `View -> (A,B)` defined in `object Dep`.
- Consequently, every definition (realisation) of the function `f`, for a given `View`, has to take an input parameter of type `A` and return a result of type `B`.

Here is the code:

```
object Rextester extends App {
    println("Hello, World!3")
 }

trait Dep[C]{
  type A
  type B
}

trait View1
trait View2


object Dep{

  type Aux[C0, A0, B0]=  Dep[C0] {type A=A0; type B= B0}

  implicit object DepInstanceView1  extends  Dep[View1] {
    type A=String
    type B=Int
  } 

  implicit object DepInstanceView2  extends  Dep[View2] {
    type A=String
    type B=String
  } 
}

trait ServerSideFun[C]
{
   def f[A,B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[C,A,B]):B
}


object ServerSideFun {
  implicit object View1Conv extends ServerSideFun[View1]{
    def f[A, B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[View1,A,B]):B = 42
  }

  implicit object View2Conv extends ServerSideFun[View2]{
    def f[A, B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[View2,A,B]):B = "42"
  }
}



object ServerSideFunAlternativeImplementation {
  implicit object View1Conv extends ServerSideFun[View1]{
    def f[A, B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[View1,A,B]):B = 43
  }

  implicit object View2Conv extends ServerSideFun[View2]{
    def f[A, B] (a:A)(implicit aux:Dep.Aux[View2,A,B]):B = "43"
  }

}
```

Comment: The `ServerSideFun` and the type level functions `C -> (A, B)` are already alright in your code. The problem is that those type-level functions don't provide anything useful for defining the actual value-level function `f`. The `Dep.Aux[View1, A, B]` can be anything. Why is `42` supposed to match *anything*? It seems as if the `Dep[C]` should be the trait that defines `f(a: A): B`.

Comment: Two problems with the edit: 1) what does `ServerSideFunAlternativeImplementation` implement, exactly? Should it be source-code compatible with `ServerSideFun` in some vague way? 2) The type `Dep.Aux[View1, A, B]` does not restrict the implicit arguments to *"**the**  type level mappings View -> (A,B) defined in object Dep"*, because additional `Dep.Aux[View1, A, B]` can be defined anywhere  by everyone else.

Comment: 1)  Depending on which implicit is in scope, a different implementation of `f` will be executed. 2) Hmmm, interesting point. Indeed. Thanks for pointing this out. However, in that case this will be seen explicity in the calling code, the user of the type class needs to take this extra mile (to deviate from the default implementation which is in scope by default), so in some sense there is still a certain kind of "soft restriction" in place.

Comment: 1) I don't quite understand what you mean by "source-code compatible" ?

Comment: To 1): *"Depending on which implicit is in scope"* -- what *type* of implicit will you look for in the first place? I'd expect something like `(impliicit ssf: ServerSideFunIntf)`, but currently `ServerSideFun` and `ServerSideFunAlternativeImplementation` share no common ancestors except `AnyRef`.

Comment: I think the second point is the more important one. Writing down `def foo[A](...): A = ` means: I guarantee that function `f` will be able to produce a value of type `A` **for all possible types A**. For such a function, an overly concrete body like `42` doesn't work, because instead of every possible `A`, it works only with `Int`. There is no way to make this compile without specifying where the concrete type `Int` comes from. There is no such thing as "soft restriction": it either works for all `A`, or it doesn't. If it doesn't have to work for all `A`, then you have to (hard-)restrict it.

Comment: Hmm, I think I start to get your point. "Writing down def foo[A](...): A = means: I guarantee that function f will be able to produce a value of type A for all possible types A." was the insight that I was overlooking, I need to ponder this idea I bit. This clarifies a lot!

Comment: To 1) : `import ServerSideFunAlternativeImplementation.View1Conv` should "override"  `ServerSideFun.View1Conv` which is "in scope" when searching for an implicit with a type of `ServerSideFun[View1]` when compiling a function like, for example, `g[T:serverSideFun] = ... `.  So if `T` is `View1` then an implicit of type `ServerSideFun[View1]` which is in scope (scope in the sense of "scope for implicit search") will be used to provide implementation for `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ServerSideFun[C]` is supposed to contain an implementation of a function `f: A => B` for some types `A` and `B`, then `ServerSideFun[C]` obviously must know what the types `A` and `B` are, otherwise it would have to compose the function `f` from some pieces that come from outside of the trait `ServerSideFun[C]`. But then we can include `type A` and `type B` into `ServerSideFun[C]`, and just drop `Dep[C]` altogether:

```
trait View1
trait View2

trait ServerSideFun[C]{
  type A
  type B
  def f(a: A): B
}

object ServerSideFun {
  implicit object View1Conv extends ServerSideFun[View1] {
    type A = String
    type B = Int
    def f(a: String): Int = 42
  }
}
```

If you want, you can re-introduce `Dep[C]`, and then extend `Dep[C]` by `ServerSideFun[C]`:

```
trait Dep[C]{
  type A
  type B
}

trait View1
trait View2

object Dep {
  trait DepInstanceView1 extends Dep[View1] {
    type A = String
    type B = Int
  } 
}

trait ServerSideFun[C] extends Dep[C] {
  def f(a: A): B
}

object ServerSideFun {
  implicit object View1Conv 
    extends ServerSideFun[View1] 
    with Dep.DepInstanceView1 {

    def f(a: String): Int = 42
  }
}
```

If `f` is not some "natural composition" of totally generic functions, then at some point you will have to write down the body of `f` in a context where `A` and `B` are known. Writing down a concrete `42` in the body, but at the same time bringing totally unspecified `A` and `B` in `Dep.Aux[View1,A,B]` from the outside doesn't work.

Comment: Many thanks Andrey ! I will try to understand your answer, it might take me a few hours (hopefully I can respond to it in a meaningful way in a day or two). I also try to clarify the intention of the question a bit, also for myself. So that I can clearly describe what is the problem/question.

Comment: I understand your answer Andrey ! Many thanks! I put your code here : http://rextester.com/MOUQX83317

Comment: @jhegedus Alright, this inspires optimism :) Does it actually do more or less what you wanted, or does it still provide a solution to a subtly different problem?

Comment: I find `trait DepInstanceView1` which is your solution of the encoding the type level dependency `C->(A,B)` very interesting, where did this idea of yours came from? I find it difficult to learn the basics of type level programming in Scala. How did you arrive at this idea? What should I learn/read so that I will be able to answer similar "type level programming related" questions on my own?

Comment: "Does it actually do more or less what you wanted, or does it still provide a solution to a subtly different problem? " I think it is a perfect answer for my question. My idea of using implicits to encode type level dependency came from the standard encoding of functional dependencies/multi parameter type classes in Scala + Aux pattern. However, it was a very bad idea for this problem. I find your solution to the problem brilliant, especially the use of inheritance which I try to avoid as a general rule of thumb but apparently it can be very useful. So this was a good lession.

Comment: @jhegedus On *"what learn/read"*: tbh, I might be the wrong person to ask, because I'm not affiliated with all those type-level-programming-heavy projects (like Scalaz, Cats, Shapeless etc.) in any way. I'm some random guy who studied math and then read a lot of stuff on category theory, type theory, logic, term-rewriting, FP, programming languages, compilers, etc. One day I then ended up writing category-theory inspired frameworks that performed some rather nasty type-level computations in functor categories. But that was somewhat unrelated to how everyone else is doing typelevel programming.

Comment: @jhegedus Whether inheritance is the best tool for the situation: I don't know. It seems not to be frowned upon when it comes to composing complex entities by mixing in bunch of traits, so in this particular situation it seemed somewhat appropriate. If you want to avoid inheritance, one could probably come up with a solution that works without it.

Comment: "math and then read a lot of stuff on category theory, type theory, logic, term-rewriting, FP, programming languages, compilers" hmmm, ok, so maybe I am not too surprised then where the inspiration for your answer might have come from ...  :) with this background you can just dream up solutions like this :)

Comment: @jhegedus Given that static type systems are essentially constrained proof-checkers for theorems, knowing how to construct lengthy proofs certainly does help.

Comment: So, where did this idea for constructing this "proof" come from ? How does your solution relate to "logic" ? Or what subject does it relate to the closest ? What was the inspiration for this solution ? Can you trace it back to something that gave you the inspiration for this solution ?

Comment: @jhegedus https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171580/room-for-andrey-tyukin-and-jhegedus